# Trouble using another module in Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I would like to store all my color values in a separate file, called "colors-rgb.lua", then just grab them by name when I need them. The basic structure of that file is:

```
colorsRGB = {
    aliceblue = {240, 248, 255},
    antiquewhite = {250, 235, 215},
    aqua = { 0, 255, 255},
    aquamarine = {127, 255, 212},
    azure = {240, 255, 255},
    beige = {245, 245, 220},
    bisque = {255, 228, 196},
    black = { 0, 0, 0},
    ...
}
```

In my main.lua, I have

```
local colors = require("colors-rgb")
local blue = colors.colorsRGB.aliceblue
```

Which gives me the error "Attempt to index local 'colors' (a boolean value)"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `return {colorsRGB = colorsRGB}` in your `colors-rgb.lua` file. Since you didn't return anything, Lua saved the execution status of your module (as a boolean value) and returned it as the result of `require` call. That's why you get the error about attempting to index a boolean value.

See [Modules and Packages](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/pil2/chapter15.pdf) chapter from Programming in Lua 2.

Comment: In this case, also, the table can still be accessed, but it's called colorsRGB as it was declared as global. He should declare it as local and then return it from the module.

Comment: Right; although the intent is clearly to access it through the result of `require`.

Answer (score 0):

The *colors-rgb.lua* needs to return a value.

```
local colorsRGB = {
    aliceblue = {240, 248, 255},
    antiquewhite = {250, 235, 215},
    aqua = { 0, 255, 255},
    aquamarine = {127, 255, 212},
    azure = {240, 255, 255},
    beige = {245, 245, 220},
    bisque = {255, 228, 196},
    black = { 0, 0, 0},
}
return colorsRGB
```